# autocomplete textbox with normal concepts javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, arrays, autocomplete

I am trying to implement a textbox autocomplete 
and here is the code

#### HTML

```
<div class="sug">
    <input type="text" id="auto" onkeyup="display(event)" onblur="hide()" autocomplete="off"/>

    <div class="suggestion" id="suggestion">
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.suggestion {
    border: solid 2px black;
}

.sug > .suggestion {
    display: none;
}

.sug > .suggestion, #auto {
    width: 100px;
}
```

#### JavaScript

```
var array = new Array();
array.push("heena");
array.push("bhawin");
array.push("aruna");
array.push("mahesh");
array.push("anshul");
array.push("jagruti");
array.push("neha");
array.push("sherry");
array.push("sonali");
var data;
var id;//for providing id to each div
function display(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 38 || e.keyCode == 40) {
        selectit(e);
    }
    data = "";
    id = 0;
    var state = $('#auto').val();
    if (state == "")//value empty
    {
        $('.suggestion').css({display: "none"});
    }
    else {
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            var key = 0;
            for (j = 0; j < state.length; j++) {
                //for the matching of the array element with the text in the textbox
                if (array[i][j] == state[j]) {
                    key++;
                }
            }
            //putting the matched array element in a div
            if (key == state.length) {
                //the whole array will be copied with the bold values inserted
                var bolde = "";
                for (var k = 0; k < key; k++) {
                    bolde += "<b>" + array[i][k] + "</b>";
                }
                for (var l = key; l < array[i].length; l++) {
                    bolde += array[i][l];
                }
                id++;
                data += "<div id='" + id + "'>" + bolde + "</div>";
            }
        }
        $('.suggestion').html(data);
        $('.suggestion').css({display: "block"});
        if (data == "") {
            $('.suggestion').css({display: "none"});
        }
    }
}
function hide() {
    $('#suggestion').css({display: "none"});
    ;
}
function selectit(e) {
    var child = document.getElementById("suggestion").childNodes;
    for (var i = 0; i < child.length; i++) {
        if (child[i].id == "1") {
            child[i].style.color = "red";   //here is the problem in the code
        }
    }
}
```

In the code I want to make the first suggestion color red on down key press
but the color is not showing

The  last comment is the region where the problem is.

Comment: You know that [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) already has all those bases covered, right? You are already using jQuery.

Comment: i know but i want to do it myself and i also know there is some simple mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are having is with the fact that you are setting the color to red and then after you return from the selectit function you are continuing down the display function and are replacing the value in .suggestion on this line:

```
$('.suggestion').html(data);
```

So at this point you remove the formatting you have just set in selectit.

If all you are trying to do is set the color based on the key selection then you should change this:

```
if (e.keyCode == 38 || e.keyCode == 40) {
    selectit(e);
}
```

to:

```
if (e.keyCode == 38 || e.keyCode == 40) {
    selectit(e);
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
function selectit(e)
```

function wasn't working properly (because of e.keyCode, I think).

[Here's working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JvwmZ/1/)

Comment: no its not because of e.keyCode as i have alerted all the e.keycodes and it is showing properly  and also you called function selectit() but refracted the code inside display() which is not what i wanted

Answer (score 0):

why not use Jquery UI? Its well tested and trusted : **[Reference](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)**

Comment: same answer as the first comment, please see above